# Getting complete datetime index of data frame in miliseconds using groupby method

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

I have a dataframe (df) with the index as datetime index in  "`%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f`" format i.e `2012-06-16 15:53:42.457000`.

I am trying to create groups of 1 second using groupby method i.e

```
x= df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1S'))
time=x.first().index[1]
print time
```

The problem is using groupby method i am only getting the timestamp in seconds only i.e "`2012-06-16 15:53:42`" , the milliseconds are excluded. Is there a way to get the complete timestamp? 
thank you

Comment: Thanks for editing it nicely Levon

Comment: I don't know just a wild guess using `1ms` instead of `1S` should do it.

Comment: @shivsn i tried that too. It shows the time in ms. However i don't want groups of ms. I want groups of 2 seconds so i tried grouping data into 2000 ms. However, the time was shown again till seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending few hours, i solved it. The functions such as **groupby, rolling etc** were giving the same problem. These functions uses a general datetime index for grouping which is mathematically the multiples of the defined frequency. There are possibilities to get `keyerror` if that index is used to get data of dataframe.

To get the complete datetime index (in milliseconds), access the daytime index of members of the individual group which were created by groupby method. i.e

```
time=  x2.first()['timeindex'][0]
```

where `timeindex` is the `datetime index` in my dataframe. [0] is the datetime index of the first member of the group, it can be incremented to get the datetime index of the second, 3rd and so on members of each groups.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a problem of formatting.

```
> df.index[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
'2016-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

[Documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: it's not the formatting problem. Ialready tried that. Normally i get the complete time in miliseconds if i use df.index [0]. But after grouping i am getting time till seconds without miliseconds.